# JSON fetching and parsing in an swift code app

Tags: json, swift

I am wanting to get experience in fetching JSON and parsing it in an iPhone or tvOS app. In the playground I got it working. But now in the either iPhone or tvOS app I can't get data into a label.

Got help with code troubleshooting, watched youtube JSON parsing and swift videos but no luck it is something very small, I am sure and I am overlooking it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var Title_Label: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @objc func getNewTitles(){
    struct ToDo : Decodable {
       let userId, id : Int
       let title : String
       let completed : Bool
    }

    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { data, _, error in
      guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }

      do {
        let todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDo.self, from: data)

        // get the values out of the struct
        let newsstring = (todo.title)
        self.Title_Label.text = newsstring
        //print(todo.userId)
        //print(todo.id)
        //print(todo.completed) 
      } catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }.resume()
  }
}
```

the problem is in the last part

why is self Title_Label needed?

The code doesn't give an error but the text is not send into the label on my TVos screen?

Comment: Nowhere in the code you're showing is `getNewTitles()` called. Are you sure that happens?

Comment: Unrelated: `self.Title_label.text = newsstring` must run on the main thread, enclose it `DispatchQueue.main.sync { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @Gereon, good point I overlooked the getNewTitles() part.still no error or output. What do you mean with self.Title_label.text = newsstring must run on the main thread, enclose it DispatchQueue.main.sync .   I am not even sure if this is the correct way to do this - Xcode proposed to fix the earlier errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please name the label according to the naming convention *lowerCamelCased*

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

You have to call the method to retrieve the data in `viewDidLoad` (in this case it's not required to be marked as `@objc`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getNewTitles()
}
```

And as mentioned in the comments you have to update the label on the main thread

```
do {
    let todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDo.self, from: data)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.titleLabel.text = todo.title
    } 
} catch { ...
```

And declare the struct at least in the scope of the class or higher

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct ToDo : Decodable {
       let userId, id : Int
       let title : String
       let completed : Bool
    }

...
```

Comment: thank you @vadian. The good thing is now it compiles and builds but it gives an exception handling error. So I got now some errors.

Comment: Of course after renaming the label you have to disconnect and reconnect it in Interface Builder to apply the change.

Comment: you were right, thx again @Vadian. all compiled succeeded. unfortunately no data in my label on my screen.

Comment: may I steal your brain some more today and ask, where you would call the function getNewTitles()? If you were to do it in this way? Or is there a smarter and simpeler way.  
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }
    do {
    let todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDo.self, from: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.titleLabel.text = todo.title }

Comment: Use the debugger. Set Breakpoints. Is the `dataTask` executed at all? Calling `getNewTitles()` in `viewDidLoad` is the usual place.

Comment: thx again this all works now. For the Title which is a string all good. userID is a number, so next hop to find out how to use numbers as a string. Thank you so much for the help @Vadian

Comment: `String(todo.userId)`

Comment: thank you, I've made the corrections. and that works.